# inner loop sum of multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT total, 
       upto10, 
       emi, 
       repo, 
       arrear, 
       res, 
       [pi], 
       Sum(emi1)        EMI, 
       Sum(repo1)       REPO, 
       Sum(repo_arrear1)REPO_ARR, 
       Sum(res1)        RESO, 
       Sum(pi1)         [PI], 
       Sum(( ( Sum(emi) / 100 ) + ( Sum([repo_arrear1]) / 100 ) ) / 
               ( ( total * 35 ) / 100 ) / 0.01) 
FROM   (SELECT Sum(total)                                           total, 
               Sum(Cast(( ( total * 55 ) / 100 ) AS DECIMAL(8, 2))) upto10, 
               Sum(emi)                                             EMI, 
               Sum(repo)                                            repo, 
               Sum([repo arrear])                                   arrear, 
               Sum(Cast(( res ) AS DECIMAL(8, 2)))                  res, 
               Sum([pi])                                            [pi], 
               Cast(( Sum(emi) / 100 ) AS DECIMAL(2, 2))            EMI1, 
               Sum(repo)                                            repo1, 
               Cast(( Sum([repo arrear]) / 100 ) AS DECIMAL(2, 2))  REPO_ARREAR1 
               , 
               Cast((Sum(emi)/100) AS DECIMAL(2, 2)) 
               + Cast((Sum([repo arrear])/100) AS DECIMAL(2, 2))    res1, 
               Cast(( Sum([pi]) / 100 ) AS DECIMAL(2, 2))           [PI1], 
               Sum(( ( Sum(emi) / 100 ) + ( Sum([repo arrear]) / 100 ) ) / ( 
                   ( total * 35 ) / 100 ) 
                   / 0.01)                                          AS emi2 
        FROM   [DCRA].[dbo].[dcc] 
        WHERE  curr_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-20' 
               AND circle = 'C1')AS a 
GROUP  BY total, 
          emi, 
          upto10, 
          repo, 
          arrear, 
          res, 
          [pi], 
          emi2
```

error message:Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sum(( ( Sum(emi) / 100 ) + ( Sum([repo_arrear1]) / 100 ) ) / ( ( total * 35 ) / 100 ) / 0.01)
```

replace with

```
(( ( Sum(emi) / 100 ) + ( Sum([repo_arrear1]) / 100 ) ) / ( ( total * 35 ) / 100 ) / 0.01)
```